# SQL MAX returns multiple values but I only want the MAX value

Tags: sql, group-by, max, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I am relatively new to SQL. So I am doing an excersise in which they ask me to select the most expensive product for every maker, and the output should have **maker**, **model**, and **price**.

I succesfully created a query that gives all models and prices for each maker,the query is as follows:

```
SELECT MODEL, MAKER, PRICE 
  FROM PC 
 INNER JOIN(SELECT MAKER, MODEL 
              FROM PRODUCT 
             WHERE MAKER='Dell') 
 USING (MODEL);
```

And what it throws is this:

| MODEL | MAKER | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | Dell | 500 |
| d2 | Dell | 600 |
| d3 | Dell | 700 |
| da | Dell | 800 |
| dzero | Dell | 1200 |

but when I introduce the MAX function, it gives me exactly the same as if there's no MAX.
This is how it looks with the MAX:

```
SELECT MODEL, MAKER, MAX(PRICE) 
  FROM PC 
 INNER JOIN(SELECT MAKER, MODEL 
              FROM PRODUCT 
             WHERE MAKER='Dell') 
 USING (MODEL) 
 GROUP BY MAKER, MODEL;
```

What it should throw is this:

| MODEL | MAKER | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dzero | Dell | 1200 |

The structure of the tables look like this:[DB STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xgKC.png)

I have to do it for all the makers, but I figured once I do it with one I could do it with all.

Comment: You should definitely check [`GROUP BY`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx/). It lets you group records by their fields, and to do aggregate operations (such as MAX amongst) on other fields.

Comment: You have 1 record per maker and model. So when you group by maker, model you will get the same  data. You can basically order the table by price in descending order then pick the first record.

Comment: what's your DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` function, if your database is eligible to use window functions such as

```
SELECT model, maker, price
  FROM(SELECT pc.model, pc.maker, pc.price,
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pc.maker ORDER BY pc.price DESC) AS dr
         FROM pc  
         JOIN product pr
           ON pr.model = pc.model 
          AND pr.maker = 'Dell' ) p
  WHERE dr = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) one could do it like:

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_product
CREATE TABLE tmp_product
-- join model with maker
-- I'd not separate the products by their types of tables unless explicitly needed
SELECT p.Maker,
    -- assumes Models amongst tables are unique
    COALESCE(pr.Model, l.Model, PC.Model) Model,
    COALESCE(pr.Price, l.Price, PC.Price) Price
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Printer pr ON p.Model = pr.Model
LEFT JOIN Laptop l ON p.Model = l.Model
LEFT JOIN PC ON p.Model = PC.Model
;

SELECT
    tp.Maker,
    -- for it's not explicitly stated how to
    -- handle multiple models from the same maker with highest price
    GROUP_CONCAT(tp.Model) AS Models,
    -- any single value pick aggregate should do
    -- as picking max price is already handled in the join
    MIN(tp.Price) AS Price
FROM tmp_product tp
LEFT JOIN tmp_product tp2 ON tp.Maker = tp2.Maker AND tp.Price < tp2.Price
WHERE tp2.Maker IS NULL
GROUP BY tp.Maker
;
```

If you're not allowed to create tables, or other queries apart from select, you could subquery `tmp_product` select in the multiple places it was used but, it is a breach for DRY.